# AS3 Php key generator

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm looking for a way to generate license keys with AS3 or PHP.
I need to calculate key with username application, version number and max user number.

For example, here is the code:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  function KeyGen($userName){
     $key = md5($userName);
     $new_key = '';
     for($i=1; $i <= 25; $i ++ ){
               $new_key .= $key[$i];
               if ( $i%5==0 && $i != 25) $new_key.='-';
     }
  return strtoupper($new_key);
  }

  $userCab="MyUserName-v6.0-12";
  $key=KeyGen($userCab);
 echo $key;
?>
```

The generates key about like this: 1AS7-09BD-96A1-CC8D-F106. 
But now, how to decrypt this key to extract the two last digit of $userCab.

Comment: Did you have a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [`md5`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt) algorithm, which is a one-way hashing algorithm. In other words, you cannot decrypt it. Normal instances that use hashing algorithms like this do not attempt to decrypt, instead they compare a given input (the user's key) with an existing hash.

If you need to decrypt the key to get information it contains, you may have to create a custom algorithm, or use a decryptable algorithm such as AES and then [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/base64_encode) the encrypted string to have something user-friendly (but it will be a long string, in most cases). Take a look at the available [`mcrypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php) functions for methods that are decryptable to find one that will suit your needs.

If you need a specific key format, as your example shows, a custom algorithm may be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot decrypt an MD5 hash. If you are going to "decrypt" it later with a check, you will want to store the values in a MySql table and encrypt the values from that table each time to check to see if it matches the key they put into it.

Don't use AS3 to encrypt anything, as someone can easily decompile your .swf and see your source code.